# \regex_set:Nn is not working properly

Tags: expl3

I was testing some regular expressions in `expl3` when I noticed that the method `\regex_set:Nn` does not seem to set a regex properly when one wants to add to it the all-matching pattern (`.`).

That can be seen in the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
    \regex_set:Nn \l_tmpa_regex {.}
    \regex_show:N \l_tmpa_regex
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

The .log file says:

```
! LaTeX3 Error: Variable '\l_tmpa_regex' is not a valid regex.
```

Does anyone know why or how to fix it?

Comment: Actually the `\regex_show:N` has the bug, the regex should work as expected, e.g., try `\regex_match:Nn \l_tmpa_regex { a } { TRUE } { FALSE }`. You could provide a bug report on [Github](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues).

Comment: I added the issue report: https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/1093

Comment: Oh, I see... Thanks, @Skillmon !

Comment: And also thanks, @egreg !